# /var keeps filling due to yum cache

Tags: linux, centos, yum, sqlite, var

the /var/cache directory keeps filling frequently due to yum metadata in centos 7.5 server.
most of the space utilized by the below files. i have set keep cache to 0 in /etc/yum.conf as well. but still not resolved. someone please throw somelight on this issue to rectify the same.

```
[4.0K]  centos7-x86_64-updates
[   0]  cachecookie
[ 52M]  filelists.xml.gz
[4.0K]  gen
[535M]  filelists.xml
[252M]  filelists.xml.sqlite
**[2.7G]  other.xml
[2.8G]  other.xml.sqlite**
[201M]  primary.xml
[255M]  primary.xml.sqlite
[716M]  other.xml.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to deal with issues like this, including:

1. Increase the size of the `/var` partition (or the `/` partition if `/var` isn't a mount-point).  If you're using LVM (or btrfs or zfs), this is fairly easy to do.  If not, you'll probably have to reboot to a [gparted](https://gparted.org/) CD or USB stick, or some similar "rescue CD" to move and resize your partitions.
2. Create a suitably-sized filesystem and mount it as `/var/cache`.  You'll need to do this while nothing is using files in /var/cache, so you can safely move its current contents into the new `/var/cache` mount-point.  This may require rebooting to single-user/emergency mode.
3. Similar to 2. above, but make a "var/cache" sub-directory on another fs (e.g. /home) that has enough free space, and replace /var/cache with a symlink to it.

   For example:

   ```
    mkdir -p /home/var/cache &&
      mv /var/cache/* /home/var/cache/ &&
      rmdir /var/cache &&
      ln -s /home/var/cache/ /var/
   ```

   Again, you should do this while the files in the original `/var/cache` aren't in use by anything.